# Rewrite URL .htaccess - Apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, webserver, url-rewriting

On my website, I would rename the URL on address bar, from

```
domain.com/economy/article.php?id=00
```

to

```
domain.com/economy/id-name-article.html
```

I wrote this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\.]*)\.html$ http://domain.com/economy/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I have an anchor with this href: `href="economy/id-name-article.html"` and when I click on it, the server is redirected on `article.php`, it runs the script in the correct way and I can view the article, but on the address bar is still written `domain.com/economy/article.php?id=00` instead `domain.com/economy/id-name-article.html`. Why?

This happens only on my online server, while locally it's all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_rewrite module is issuing a redirect to your browser rather than transparently rewriting the url, causing you to see the new url in your browser.

Try removing the `http://domain.com` portion from your RewriteRule to see if it avoids the redirect to your browser by changing the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^\.]*)\.html$ /economy/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If that fails, you could also use the proxy flag [P] to force apache to transparently fetch the page and return it to your users without the redirect. I don't recommend this approach since it can have security implications but it should work if the above doesn't.

**EDIT**: To clarify, rewriting the url with a fully-qualified domain rather than a relative uri tells apache that the redirect is on a different server, and therefore it doesn't know that the new url is accessible on the same host without redirecting the client.

Comment: Perfect. I have simply removed the `http://domain.com` portion and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it worked. If that's the correct answer please mark it, thanks.